# IF ELSE condition when working with numbers

Tags: php, if-statement, resolution, screen-resolution

There is a problem that my brain I can not afford to solve, namely the creation of if-else conditions:
960x540 is the value for which we obtain the value of "1", all values ​​less than this (for example 800x480) get again value "1", a similar situation 540x960 (480x800, etc. in descending order with smaller numbers), if the value of the number of 960x540 increases from one side (for example 1000x540 or 960x600), then give "2" in a variable instead of "1" ... I hope I have clearly described the problem.
I was advised to multiply for example 960x540, and an overall value, make it easier to work with it. But the problem lies in the fact that I work with a screen resolution of mobile phones and is not suitable for the reason that we forget about the desktop with the low resolution, like 800x600 pixels which are the cumulative number of much less than that of the screen with a resolution of 540x960… Sorry for bad English.

Comment: "I hope I have clearly described the problem". Err, I do not think so.

Comment: @user1103744 Your request is all plain text and not well structured, this makes understanding the problem more difficult. I tried to get the problem and tried to explain it in my answer, too. Please check if I got the request towards resolutions right. Maybe edit your question and add a list then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to explain your request more clear. (I did not edit your question since I'm not sure I got everything right)

- 960x540 => 1

Smaller values => 1

- 800x480

Greater values (each dimension) => 2

- 1000x540
- 960x600

You have to look at both x- and y-resolutions and determine your result.
Do not try to check for specific resolutions, because this will get a really complex condition.

- Extract x and y (width and height).
- Test them separately.

Your if-statement should look like this:

```
if ($x > 960 || $y > 540)
    $result = 2;
else
    $result = 1;
```

Comment: If you develop for mobile devices, you may run into problems supporting portrait and landscape view. In your statement you rely on a resolution where `x>y`. I don't know why you need this in you PHP code, but if it's for layout purposes, you might want to check for CSS media-queries.

Comment: You understand me perfectly. Thank you for your answer and your understanding! By the way, I'm using media queries, and the problem is that I want to remove large images using this solution on php (+ js and cookies)

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in this bit of math:

By passing the width of a video you can get the ratio of height (4:3):

`$height = round(floor($width/1.330),-1);`  You could change 1.330 to 1.770 for (16:9)

Example that loops through and adds 160:

```
$i=160;
while($i<=1024){
    $height = round(floor($i/1.330),-1);
    $ratios[]=array('width'=>$i,'height'=>$height);
    $i=($i+160);
}
print_r($ratios);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [width] => 160
            [height] => 120
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [width] => 320
            [height] => 240
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [width] => 480
            [height] => 360
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [width] => 640
            [height] => 480
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [width] => 800
            [height] => 600
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [width] => 960
            [height] => 720
        )

)
*/
```

Hope its of some interest.